# What is so novel about Machine learning in general and nueral network in particular?

Tags: machine-learning

To give a brief one-line description of machine learning: It is basically a function approximation given sample and hypothesis class. But this question is already tackled by statisticians (parameter as well as non-parameter). So is it a old wine in a new bottle?

Comment: You may want to read Leo Breiman’s paper “Statistical Modeling: The Two Cultures”. It gets at the difference in outlooks and approaches between the ML and classic stats paradigms.

Comment: @Dave Maybe you could help us understand what the question is?  With the typos, the informal language, and structural problems with the English, I just can't make sense of it.

Comment: Perhaps you meant "function approximator" rather than "function appropriator"? Please clarify.

Comment: Is "hypothesis lass" intented to be "hypothesis and loss"?

Comment: @Galen it was probably meant to be "hypothesis class".

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy That would make more sense. Hopefully the OP clarifies.